Retrieve GeoPackage QField iOS
I have created a QField project With a point layer to capture data and to store photos in a DCIM folder.
The project is being used in iOS.
The project was created using Qfield cloud.
The project is now 6GB file size because of the photos. Even with the pro version I cannot get all the info because it is limited to 1GB. In Android it is really easy to share the GeoPackage and DCIM folder, but in iOS it is really protected. I navigate to the folder files in Qfield but it is empty, I see there is a route leading to var/mobile/data ... but I have not manage to access those app folders in iOS.
Has anyone dealt with this or have any suggestions how to get to those app folders?
